# Iterate up to and including position

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

Probably very simple but can't get my head around it atm

I have this

```
// standard std::map and std::map::iterator
auto pos = map.find(val);
for(auto it = map.begin; it != pos; ++it)
```

I want to search for an element and then process all elements before (container is ordered, so just in iteration order) and including the find location, however this doesn't appear to examine the final element at position 'pos'. How can I achieve this?

Comment: If you use a `do`-`while` loop, the condition is checked after the loop body and not before.

Comment: `if(pos != map.end()) //process pos here` ?

Comment: map.begin() don't forget the ()

Comment: shouldn't it be `for(auto it = map.begin(); it != pos; ++it)` additionally there is no check for whether the returned `it` does not equal to `map.end()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just move things around.

```
auto pos = map.find(val);
for(auto it = map.begin(); it != map.end(); ++it)
{
    // Do something

    if (it == pos)
       break;
}
```

If it's possible that the value does not exist in the map, this will simply end up iterating over the entire map and that's why `it != map.end();` is explicitly needed, to catch this particular runaway train...

Caution: if you have explicit `continue`s inside the `for` loop, some additional TLC will be needed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to differentiate between the cases where `val` is found in `map` and otherwise:

```
void f(/*map::[const_]iterator*/ it);

auto pos = map.find(val);
for (auto it = map.begin(); it != pos; ++it)
    f(it);
if (pos != map.end())
    f(pos);
```

You could use a `do...while()` loop but you would have to check for `pos!=end()` each time.